# Apex script unhandled trigger exception Salesforce

Tags: exception, triggers, salesforce, apex, unhandled

I've just received a developer script exception email for a trigger I've got in a production environment:

```
Apex script unhandled trigger exception by user/organization: 00590000002GfMD/00D90000000cIze
SetContactDonorCampaign: execution of BeforeInsert
caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []
Trigger.SetContactDonorCampaign: line 25, column 1
```

The error doesn't give me any id for the record it failed on, which is a bit annoying. The trigger itself just recognises when a Payment_Information__c record is created with the lookup Contact__c populated, and sets a multi-select picklist on that Contact to include "Donor" if it doesn't already.

```
trigger SetContactDonorCampaign on Payment_Information__c (before insert,before update) {

    for(Payment_Information__c donation : Trigger.new)
    {
        Contact reg = new Contact();
        if(donation.Contact__c != NULL)
        {
            reg = [SELECT id, Campaign__c FROM Contact WHERE Id = :donation.Contact__c];
            String regCampaign = '';
            if (reg.Campaign__c != NULL)
            {
                if (!reg.Campaign__c.contains('Donor'))
                {
                  regCampaign = reg.Campaign__c + ';Donor';
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            } else {            
                regCampaign = 'Donor';
            }
            reg.Campaign__c = regCampaign;
        }
        if (reg != NULL)
        {
            update reg;
        }
    }   
}
```

Without a specific record to look up (the system doesn't even have a Payment Information record with modified date matching this error), any suggestions on what's failing here?

Comment: You are calling this in before insert, In before insert actual insert in not committed, so it may possible that not have id fields in contact object. and Your contact object is not null in any conditions because you have added "Contact reg = new Contact();" in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact object is not null even donation.Contact__c is null.
because you created new contact object each time.

```
Contact reg = new Contact();

if (reg != NULL)
{
        update reg;
}
```

above condition is always executed. That's way this error is occur.

Please change your Code to bellow.

```
trigger SetContactDonorCampaign on Payment_Information__c (before insert,before update) {

for(Payment_Information__c donation : Trigger.new)
{
    Contact reg = null;
    if(donation.Contact__c != NULL)
    {
        reg = [SELECT id, Campaign__c FROM Contact WHERE Id = :donation.Contact__c];
        String regCampaign = '';
        if (reg.Campaign__c != NULL)
        {
            if (!reg.Campaign__c.contains('Donor'))
            {
              regCampaign = reg.Campaign__c + ';Donor';
            } else {
                return;
            }
        } else {            
            regCampaign = 'Donor';
        }
        reg.Campaign__c = regCampaign;
    }
    if (reg != NULL)
    {
        update reg;
    }
}
```

}